# Python Product Inventory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a simple product inventory which essentially allows user to add products, display them and deduce the inventory value. I am stuck in the part where the inventory value is deduced.  What I want the code to do here is multiply the product `price * product quantity` for each added product and return the sum. When I run the code, I get the error,  `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. I am new at Python, would appreciate any guidance!

Here is a portion of the code:

```
class Product:

    def __init__(self, idnum, price, quantity):
        self.idnum = idnum
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity        

class Inventory:

    def __init__(self):
        self.productlist = []        

    def add_product(self):
        idnum = int(input('Enter id: '))
        price = int(input('Enter price: '))
        quantity = int(input('Enter quantity: '))
        self.productlist.append(Product(idnum, price, quantity))
        return self.productlist

    def display(self):  
        for product in self.productlist:
            print(product.idnum, product.price, product.quantity)

    def inventory_value(self):
        for product in self.productlist:
            return sum(product.price*product.quantity)
```

Comment: What is `sum(product.price*product.quantity)` supposed to mean, provided that `product.price` and `product.quantity` are _integers_, their product is an _integer_ as well, and summing _one_ integer with nothing doesn't make much sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to sum *all the products (the result of multiplication)* like that:

```
def inventory_value(self):
    running_sum = 0
    for product in self.productlist:
        running_sum += product.price * product.quantity

    return running_sum
```

Or simply:

```
def inventory_value(self):
    return sum(product.price * product.quantity for product in self.productlist)
```

Notice that this `sums *over a collection*, and not a *single* integer, like in your case:

```
>>> [x * (x + 1) for x in range(5)]
[0, 2, 6, 12, 20]
>>> sum(x * (x + 1) for x in range(5))
40
```